# Salvar dados de uma textbox em uma classe e exibir em uma datagrid

Tags: c#, array, winforms, datagridview

Estou fazendo um programa para cadastro simples, sem utilizar banco de dados, só com array. O programa já estava funcional quando eu notei que a parte mais importante estava errada pois eu não tinha entendido direito. Eu acabei não utilizando a classe Pessoa que criei, e sim acabei manipulando tudo com textbox e a datagrid que eu exibo os cadastros.

Não consegui entender direito como puxar os dados da classe Pessoa (que eu coloquei o código abaixo) para quando eu utilizar uma textBox para salvar os dados nessa classe, em um array. E com esses dados salvos, exibir cada cadastro em uma linha da datagrid.

```
List<Pessoa> list = new List<Pessoa>();

        public class Pessoa
    {

        //atributos privados da classe Pessoa
        private string nome;
        private string endereço;
        private string ano_nascimento;
        private string telefone;

        //propriedades públicas, read-only
        public Pessoa(string nome, string endereço, string ano_nascimento, string telefone)
        {
            this.nome = nome;
            this.endereço = endereço;
            this.ano_nascimento = ano_nascimento;
            this.telefone = telefone;
        }

        //método construtor get(pega a informação) e set(grava)
        public string getNome()
        {
            return nome;
        }

        public string getEndereço()
        {
            return endereço;
        }

        public string getAno_nascimento()
        {
            return ano_nascimento;
        }

        public string getTelefone()
        {
            return telefone;
        }

        public void setNome(string nome)
        {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

        public void setEndereço(string endereço)
        {
            this.endereço = endereço;
        }

        public void setAno_nascimento(string ano_nascimento)
        {
           this.ano_nascimento = ano_nascimento;
        }

        public void setTelefone(string telefone)
        {
            this.telefone = telefone;
        }

        public void AlterarEndereco(string novoEndereco)
        {
            endereço = novoEndereco;
        }

        public void AlterarTelefone(string novoTelefone)
        {
            telefone = novoTelefone;
        }

    }
```

Parte do código que eu tentei salvar o cadastro em um array depois de colocar os dados em cada textbox.

```
private void bt_salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             list.Add(new Pessoa(txt_nome.Text, txt_endereco.Text, /*dataNasc*/ txt_ano.Text, txt_tele.Text));

        }
```

E essa é a parte do código para salvar que eu vi que realmente estava errada e eu não estava lidando com os atributos da classe.

```
string[] dados = { txt_nome.Text, txt_endereco.Text, txt_ano.Text, txt_tele.Text, txt_registro.Text };

        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dados);
```

Estou programando uma Windows Forms Application em C# no Visual Studio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na classe chamada “Pessoa”, com os atributos “Nome”, “Endereço”, “AnoNascimento” e “Telefone”, estou usando os atributos privados que são disponibilizados pelas propriedades públicas(read only).
Abaixo o código atual:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    List<Pessoa> listcadastro = new List<Pessoa>();



    //apagar tudo que estava sendo escrito na opção de cadastro atual
    void reset()
    {
        txt_nome.Clear();
        txt_endereco.Clear();
        txt_ano.Clear();
        txt_registro.Clear();
        txt_tele.Clear();
        bt_pfisica.Checked = false;
        bt_pjuridica.Checked = false;
    }

    private void bt_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reset();
    }


    public class Pessoa
    {
        private string nome;
        private string endereço;
        private string ano_nascimento;
        private string telefone;

        /*
        //propriedades públicas, read-only
        public Pessoa(string nome, string endereço, string ano_nascimento, string telefone)
        {
            this.nome = nome;

            this.endereço = endereço;

            this.ano_nascimento = ano_nascimento;

            this.telefone = telefone;

        }*/

        public string Nome
        {
            get
            {
                return nome;
            }

            set
            {
                nome = value;
            }
        }

        public string Endereço
        {
            get
            {
                return endereço;
            }

            set
            {
                endereço = value;
            }
        }

        public string Ano_nascimento
        {
            get
            {
                return ano_nascimento;
            }

            set
            {
                ano_nascimento = value;
            }
        }

        public string Telefone
        {
            get
            {
                return telefone;
            }

            set
            {
                telefone = value;
            }
        }
    }



    private void bt_salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



         listcadastro.Add(new Pessoa() {Ano_nascimento = txt_ano.Text, Nome = txt_nome.Text, Endereço = txt_endereco.Text, Telefone = txt_tele.Text });

         dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
         dataGridView1.DataSource = listcadastro; 
    }

    private void novoMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txt_nome.Enabled = true;
        txt_ano.Enabled = true;
        txt_endereco.Enabled = true;
        txt_tele.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void limpa_dados()
    {
        txt_nome.ResetText();// limpa o nome
        txt_tele.ResetText();// limpa o telefone
        txt_endereco.ResetText();// limpa o endereço
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_nome.Enabled = false;
        txt_ano.Enabled = false;
        txt_endereco.Enabled = false;
        txt_tele.Enabled = false;
        txt_registro.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void bt_pfisica_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bt_pfisica.Checked)
        {
            txt_registro.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void bt_pjuridica_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bt_pjuridica.Checked)
        {
            txt_registro.Enabled = true;
        }
    }




}
```

}

Comment: Você consegue ser mais específico? Quer dizer, dar mais detalhes sobre esta questão do grid que você pretende utilizar, por exemplo

Comment: Eu acabei editando a pergunta e adicionei mais códigos, se ainda não ficar bem claro posso dar mais informações sem problemas. Estou tentando ser objetivo mas acho que não estou conseguindo

Comment: Algum motivo em especial para você não utlizar os `get` e `set` do C#? https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/w86s7x04.aspx

Comment: Nenhum, até vi que também era outra forma de fazer o método construtor. É melhor fazer com ele?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente eu alteraria a sua classe pessoa para utilizar os [`get`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/w86s7x04.aspx) e [`set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/w86s7x04.aspx) do C#

```
public class Pessoa
{
    private string nome;
    private string endereço;
    private string ano_nascimento;
    private string telefone;

    public string Nome
    {
        get
        {
            return nome;
        }

        private set
        {
            nome = value;
        }
    }

    public string Endereço
    {
        get
        {
            return endereço;
        }

        private set
        {
            endereço = value;
        }
    }

    public string Ano_nascimento
    {
        get
        {
            return ano_nascimento;
        }

        private set
        {
            ano_nascimento = value;
        }
    }

    public string Telefone
    {
        get
        {
            return telefone;
        }

        private set
        {
            telefone = value;
        }
    }

    public Pessoa(string nome, string endereço, string ano_nascimento, string telefone)
    {
        this.nome = nome;

        this.endereço = endereço;

        this.ano_nascimento = ano_nascimento;

        this.telefone = telefone;

    }
}
```

Depois disso, no seu botão salvar, basta adicionar os itens na lista de pessoa e referenciar no [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) através da propriedade [`DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list.Add(new Pessoa(txt_ano.Text, txt_nome.Text, txt_endereco.Text, txt_tele.Text));

    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
}
```

Na forma declarativa de `Field` (campo) e [`Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) (propriedade) como foi escrita a classe Pessoa. O método `get` retorna o campo associado a propriedade, o `set` atribui o `value` ao campo da propriedade.

> A palavra-chave contextual value é usado em o acessador set nas
>   declarações de propriedade comum. Ele é semelhante a um parâmetro de
>   entrada em um método. A palavra value faz referência ao valor que o
>   código do cliente está tentando atribuir à propriedade.

Fonte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-Br/library/a1khb4f8.aspx

Código fonte completo: https://github.com/pablotdv/StackOverflow/tree/master/WindowsFormsApplication2

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54722/discussion-on-answer-by-pablo-tondolo-de-vargas-salvar-dados-de-uma-textbox-em-u)